# How to disable ctrl-v in Vim?

Tags: linux, vim, vimrc

In `/etc/vimrc`, how do I disable the <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd> feature. I.e, disable visual block.

Comment: Maybe it's no possible remove visual-block feature from vim, why you need to remove it ?

Answer (score 4):

From the help in `vim` for `CTRL-V-alternative`:

> Since CTRL-V is used to paste, you can't use it to start a blockwise Visual
>   selection.  You can use CTRL-Q instead.  You can also use CTRL-Q in Insert
>   mode and Command-line mode to get the old meaning of CTRL-V.  But CTRL-Q
>   doesn't work for terminals when it's used for control flow.

These lines are from the `mswin.vim` file:

```
" CTRL-V and SHIFT-Insert are Paste
map <C-V>               "+gP
map <S-Insert>          "+gP

cmap <C-V>              <C-R>+
cmap <S-Insert>         <C-R>+
```